# problemas con objetos en javascript

Tags: javascript, prototipos

Tengo un objeto tablero que es el siguiente:

```
   function Tablero(){

    this.mapa = 
                 [[0,0,0,0,0,0],
                  [0,0,0,0,0,0],
                  [0,0,0,0,0,0],
                  [0,0,0,0,0,0],
                  [0,0,0,0,0,0],
                  [0,0,0,0,0,0]];


    this.habilitarPos = function(){
        var coorCompleta = this.disponible().split("-");        
        return [coorCompleta[0],coorCompleta[1]];       
    };

    this.disponible = function(){ 
            var nuevoDisp = []; //retorna un arreglo de las posiciones 
            this.mapa.forEach(function(fila,indexf) {
                fila.forEach(function(colum,indexc) {
                    if(colum === 0){
                        nuevoDisp.push(indexf+"-"+indexc);
                    }
                });
            });
            //retorna una posicion cualquiera del arreglo de posiciones vacias
            return nuevoDisp[Math.floor((Math.random() * nuevoDisp.length))]

    };  

    this.actualizar = function(elemento){
        if(this.mapa[elemento.posfila][elemento.poscol] !== 0){
            if(this.mapa[elemento.posfila][elemento.poscol].tipo == 3){
                this.mapa[elemento.posfila][elemento.poscol] =  elemento;           
            }else{
                this.mapa[elemento.posfila][elemento.poscol] =  4;
            }
        }else{
            this.mapa[elemento.posfila][elemento.poscol] =  elemento;
        }
    };

    this.quitarCaballo = function(elemento){
         if(this.mapa[elemento.posfila][elemento.poscol] == 4){ 
            if(elemento.tipo == 1){
                this.mapa[elemento.posfila][elemento.poscol] =  maquina;
            }else if(elemento.tipo == 2){
                this.mapa[elemento.posfila][elemento.poscol] =  usuario;
            }   
         }else{
             this.mapa[elemento.posfila][elemento.poscol] =  0;
         }
    };

    this.pintarme = function(){

        this.mapa.forEach(function(fila,indexf) { //recorrer mi mapa y pintar 0 = vacio, 4 = usuario y maquina, objeto = objeto
                fila.forEach(function(elemento,indexc){
                    if(elemento !== 0 && elemento !== 4){
                        switch(elemento.tipo) {
                                case 1://usuario
                                    $("#"+elemento.posfila+elemento.poscol).html("<img src='img/usuario.png' width='50px' height='50px' />");
                                    break;
                                case 2://maquina
                                    $("#"+elemento.posfila+elemento.poscol).html("<img src='img/maquina.png' width='50px' height='50px' />");
                                    break;                              
                                case 3://manzana
                                    $("#"+elemento.posfila+elemento.poscol).html("<img src='img/manzana.png' width='50px' height='50px' />");
                                    break;  
                                default:
                                    $("#"+indexf+indexc).html("");
                            } 
                    }else if(elemento == 4){
                                $("#"+indexf+indexc).html("<img src='img/UM.png' width='50px' height='50px' />");
                    }else{
                        $("#"+indexf+indexc).html("");
                    }
                });
            });
    }

}
```

**al crearlo :**

```
var tablero_Original = new Tablero();
```

**despues agrego un objeto en el arreglo que esta en this.mapa, el objeto que ingreso es el siguente:**

```
function Caballo(usu) {
    this.posinicial = tablero.habilitarPos();
    this.posfila = 0; //this.posinicial[0];
    this.poscol = 0; //this.posinicial[1];
    this.manzanas = 0;
    this.tipo = usu; // 1 usuario, 2 maquina
    this.dondeSaltar = function(){
        return movimientosValidos(parseInt(this.posfila),parseInt(this.poscol));
    };
    this.setPos = function(pf,pc) {     
            this.poscol = pc;
            this.posfila = pf;
        };
}


maquina = new Caballo(2);// inicio la maquina   
tablero_Original.actualizar(maquina); //ingreso la maquina en el tablero
```

**AHORA, deseo crear un nuevo tablero que este exactamente igual al original**

```
var tableroClon =  new Tablero();
tableroClon.mapa = tablero_Original.mapa;
```

***el problema*** es que cuando hago eso y quiero agregar al tableroClon un objeto (es decir queda con el objeto del tablero original y otro que agrego nuevo):

```
usuario = new Caballo(1);// inicio el usuario   
tableroClon.actualizar(usuario); //ingreso el usuario en el tablero
```

Se me actualizan los dos tableros, es decir los dos tableros quedan igual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes clonar el objeto, cuando haces:

```
tableroClon.mapa = tablero_Original.mapa;
```

Estas haciendo referencia al mismo objeto almacenado en memoria, por lo que los cambios que realices en uno se verán reflejados en el otro.

### La solucion:

```
function copiarObjeto(objeto) {
    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(objeto));
}

tableroClon.mapa = copiarObjeto(tablero_Original.mapa);
```

Para información más detallada:
http://www.zsoltnagy.eu/cloning-objects-in-javascript/

Básicamente convierte el objeto a JSON y depués lo vuelve a convertir, así desreferencia en memoria todo lo referenciado. Mira el articulo, es bastante interesante.

Comment: Sos lo mejor que me ha pasado jajajajaaj, Gracias

Comment: Jajaja, de nada. Un saludo.